# How to update SharePoint 2010 Column with SharePoint Username via OnClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint-2010

Good morning, I come to you guys looking for some assistance getting two functions to work.  I think I'm almost there but I'm missing something.  I cannot get the field in SharePoint to update but I can get my document to open no problem.  Is something missing in the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fnUpdateRecord(userId, id) {

            $.getJSON("PROGRAM/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/List(" + id + ")?$select=ViewBy", function (data) {

                            var viewby = data.d.ViewBy;
                            var username = userId;
                            var doc = new Object();
                                doc.ViewBy = username;

                            $.ajax({
                                            method: "POST",
                                            url: "PROGRAM/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List(" + id + ")",
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            processData: false,
                                            beforeSend: beforeSendFunction,
                                            data: JSON.stringify(doc),
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            error: function (xhr) {
                                                            alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                                            },
                                            success: function () {  

                                            }
                            });
            });

}

function fnRecordAccess(id, path) {
            $.ajax({
                            url: "GetCurrentUser.aspx",
                            context: document.body
                            }).success(function(result) {
                                            var userId = $(result).find('.wtf').text()
                                            fnUpdateRecord(userId, id);
                    window.open(path, "othrWn");
                            }).error(function(error) {
                                            console.log(error);

            });


}
</script>
```

I think call those functions via an OnClick:

```
onclick='fnRecordAccess(" + i.Id + ", &quot;" + path + "&quot;)'><i class='fa fa-lg fa-pencil'></i> View</a>
```

I can get the item/infopath form to load in another window but it doesn't seem to run the function to add the username in the ViewBy column.  Any ideas?  Thank you for assisting!

Edit: Added fnCountrySearch; this calls the other functions.

```
function fnCountrySearch(choice) {

    fnWaitDialog("show");

    var searchId = choice;

    $("#tableBody tr").remove();

    $.getJSON("PROGRAM/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/List?$filter=Country eq '" + searchId + "'&$orderby=Name", function (data) {

        var d = data.d;
        if (d.results.length == 0) {
            $("#noResultsAlert").show();
            $("#notingQueried").hide();
        }
        else {
            $.each(d.results, function (n, i) {

            var path = i.Path + "/" + i.Name;

                $("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>" + "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-default' class='pull-left' href='#' onclick='fnRecordAccess(" + i.Id + ", &quot;" + path + "&quot;)'><i class='fa fa-lg fa-pencil'></i> View</a></td></tr>");


            });

            $("#noResultsAlert").hide();
            $("#notingQueried").hide();
        }
    })
    .always(function () {
        fnWaitDialog("hide");
    });
}
```

The beforeSendFunction:

```
function beforeSendFunction(xhr) {

// Manipulate headers for update
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
// Using MERGE so that the entire entity doesn't need to be sent over the wire.
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", 'MERGE');
```

}

Comment: Can we also see your `beforeSendFunction` function?

Comment: I attached it above as an edit.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing it up there yet. Do you define a function called `beforeSendFunction`? I'm seeing a reference to it in the parameter passed to your ajax call in `fnUpdateRecord` (specifically the line that reads `beforeSend: beforeSendFunction,`).

Comment: function beforeSendFunction(xhr) {

 // Manipulate headers for update
 xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
 // Using MERGE so that the entire entity doesn't need to be sent over the wire.
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", 'MERGE');
}

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to compare your code with the examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798303.aspx) but haven't identified a problem yet. Do you get any errors in the F12 developer console when you run your code?

Comment: I don't have any in Chrome but I have some in IE but I just can't trust IE since its forced in IE 8 compatibility mode.  I'm testing in Chrome ATM.  Thank you for the examples.  I'll take a look at those and see if I can come up with anything.  The idea here is that each time someone views a record - it puts a line in a SharePoint 2010 Rich Text Field.  I.E. Ross Bethune @ 4/19/2016 11:08 AM; Thriggle @ 11:09 AM.

Comment: Got it!  Not sure what happened but I move the beforeSendFunction to the last function location and it worked and successfully appended the Username & Date to a Rich Text Field.  I'm not sure the protocol for an additional question but do you know how to get it to not replace the previous record and add a line after a ;?

var doc = new Object();
                                 doc.ViewBy = username + " @ " + output + ";";

Comment: I think you'll need to query the field value first to get the current value. Then you'll be able to set the ViewBy field like so `doc.ViewBy = username + " @ " + output + ";\n" + currentValue;` (assuming you've stored the field's current value in the `currentValue` variable).

Comment: Also, feel free to post your own answer to your question, now that you've solved it. That'll help people to realize that your question isn't still in need of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**REST**

To compare your code with published examples, you can refer to Microsoft's documentation of SharePoint 2010's REST interface here:

- Data Access for Client Applications: [Using the REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)
- Reference Implementation: Client: [Using the REST Interface from JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798303.aspx)

**JSOM**

SharePoint 2010 does have a [JavaScript client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx) that you can use as an alternative to the REST API. This can be an especially attractive option if you find yourself invoking the REST API via JavaScript, since the client object model does not require additional libraries.

If you were to rewrite your `fnUpdateRecord` method to use the JavaScript client object model it would look like this:

```
fnUpdateRecord(userId, id){
    var listName = "List", fieldName = "ViewBy", newValue = userId + " @ " + new Date() + ";\n";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var item = list.getItemById(id);
    clientContext.load(item);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,function(){
        // get current field value...
        var currentValue = item.get_item(fieldName);
        item.set_item(fieldName, newValue + currentValue);
        item.update();
        // update the field with the new value
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
    }),Function.createDelegate(this,function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());}));
}
```

Note that when using the JavaScript Client Object Model, you need to wait for the `SP.JS` library to load first. This can be accomplished using the built-in `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method like so:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunctionName,"SP.JS");
```

or

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    // your code here
},"SP.JS");
```